# Upsert fails when using as() and coalesce()

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to create an upsert traversal in Gremlin. Update an edge if it exists, otherwise add a new edge.

```
g.V("123")
.as("user")
.V("456")
.as("post")
.inE("like")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold()
  .property("likeCount", 1),
  __.addE("like")
  .from("user")
  .to("post")
)
```

This returns an error.

> The provided traverser does not map to a value: []->[SelectOneStep(last,post)]

I've narrowed this down to the `to("post")` step. From within `coalesce` it can't see `post` from `as("post")`. It is also unable to see `user`.

This is strange to me because the following does work:

```
g.V("123")
.as("user")
.V("456")
.as("post")
.choose(
  __.inE("like"),
  __.inE("like")
    .property("likeCount", 1),
  __.addE("like")
    .from("user")
    .to("post")
)
```

From within the `choose()` step I do have access to `user` and `post`.

I'd like to use the more efficient upsert pattern but can't get past this issue. I could just look up the `user` and `post` from within `coalesce` like so:

```
g.V("123")
.as("user")
.V("456")
.as("post")
.inE("like")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold()
  .property("likeCount", 1),
  __.V("456")
  .as("post")
  .V("123")
  .addE("like")
  .to("post")
)
```

But repeating that traversal seems inefficient. I need `post` and `user` in the outer traversal for other reasons.

Why can't I access `user` and `post` from within a `coalesce` in my first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that as soon as you hit the `fold()` step in your code you [lose the path history](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-barrier-steps), which means that it will not know `user` or `post` are referring to.  `fold()` is what is known as a ReducingBarrierStep which means that many results are collected into a single result.  The way I think about it is that because you have converted many results to one, anything like aliases that were added (e.g. `user` and `post`) no longer really have meaning as they have all been collected into a single element.

However you can rewrite your query as shown here to achieve the desired result:

```
g.V("456")
.inE("like")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold()
  .property("likeCount", 1),
  __.addE("like")
  .from(V("123"))
  .to(V("456"))
)
```

I am also not sure if you meant to only add a like count on an existing edge or if you wanted to add the like count to the edge in either case which would be like this:

```
g.V("456")
.inE("like")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold(),
  __.addE("like")
  .from(V("123"))
  .to(V("456"))
).property("likeCount", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I oversimplified the example a bit too much and the `count` step didn't make sense.